# How to join a transaction table to an historical lookup table based on transaction date?

Tags: sql, select, join

I am trying to run a SQL query with a transaction table and a historical table that looks like this:

Historical Table:

```
Active Date    Inactive Date    Attribute   CustID
1/1/2013        1/15/2013         Blue         A 
1/15/2013       1/30/2013         Green        A
```

Transaction Table:

```
Transaction Date     CustID
1/12/2013              A
1/28/2013              A

And I would want to return
```

Result:

```
Transaction Date     CustID   Attribute 
1/12/2013              A        Blue
1/28/2013              A        Green
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` the tables on the `custid` and then the `transaction date` with both the `active date` and `inactive date`:

```
select t.`transaction date`,
  t.custid,
  h.attribute
from transactions t
inner join historical h
  on t.custid = h.custid
  and t.`transaction date` >= h.`Active Date`
  and t.`transaction date` <= h.`Inactive Date`
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86e88/2)

Answer (score 0):

As I've seen the result, the `date of the transaction` falls between the `Active Date` and `inActive` date from the historical table. The result can be achieved by joining the table on two conditions: that it match with `CustID` and that it falls between the two dates.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.Attribute
FROM    TransactionTable a
        INNER JOIN HistoricalTable b
            ON  a.CustID = b.CustID AND
                a.TransactionDATE BETWEEN b.ActiveDate AND b.InActiveDATE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1559/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)